# Can't ping server, but server can ping client

Tags: ip, ping, firewall, windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard using a D-Link router. I want to Configure it using Static IP Addresses.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to turn off the firewall and ping to test the response.

If that does work, then re-enable the firewall and allow ping.

https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/20/how-to-enable-ping-in-windows-server-2012/